# Замена arcpy.management.CopyRaster средствами gdal

Tags: python, arcgis, gdal, tif

Есть код на *python*, преобразующий `tif`-снимок. Используется библиотека *arcgis*.

```
raster_name = Raster(in_raster).name
    arcpy.management.CopyRaster(in_raster, out_folder + raster_name , '', 0, 256,
                                'None', 'None', '16_BIT_UNSIGNED', 'None',
                                'None', 'TIFF', 'None', 'CURRENT_SLICE', 'NO_TRANSPOSE')
```

Необходимо выполнить тоже преобразование средствами `gdal`.
Какими методами нужно воспользоваться?